# SOCKET ADDRESS not working on some PCs - C++

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc

I have a problem regarding my code in SOCKET Programming.

```
WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        //system("pause");
        //return;
    }
    SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    struct hostent *host;

    host = gethostbyname("myServer");

    /****************************/
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
    /****************************/
 //CRASHING STARTS HERE
    if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0) {
        strMessage = "Connection FAILED :( Try Again";
        AfxMessageBox(strMessage);
        //return;
    }
    /******************************/
    send(Socket, params, strlen(params), 0);
    char buffer[160];
    strcpy_s(buffer, "");
    int nDataLength;
    /*******************************/
    while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 160, 0)) > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    /*******************************/
```

My MFC static library does not execute in some computers. So i decided to cut each of the functions in my code 1 by 1 to know what part of the code does not work. Above is my code for reference. It works well with some PCs but does not even compile on others. I dont know why. Is it because of compatibility?

I get the error ...exe is not a valid win32 application. the idea of the program is to give out the mac add ip and serial of the computer to a server for verification.

Can someone help me debug this? Thanks!

Machine Details:

Windows 10 64bit

intel x64

Comment: Have you checked that `gethostbyname` returned a valid pointer? And what is your *actual* problem? You seem to ask many different questions (you mention crashing, not running, not compiling) without enough details to answer any of them.

Comment: What exactly is `params`? Also, your `while` loop will happily run right off the end of the buffer. (Say your buffer happens to initialize to all 255's and you read one character, say a space. Boom.)

Comment: The program does not compile? What is the compiler error message?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for being vague. was typing it in a rush. The program actually compiles. It just crashes on some computers once this line is executed connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, I am aware of that. That is why I set up my buffer with the an exact limit to catch the response.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz params is my URL. It contains the directory in the webserver that leads to the api request file that I did and it also contains the parameters that I will be passing.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes! it has a valid pointer. My main problem is that it crashes on some computers.

Comment: Check that `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)` does not return `INVALID_SOCKET`.

Comment: The code crashes on some systems, because you aren't handling, or even checking for error conditions. If you want to prevent the application from crashing, handle errors, and don't wait for the system to dismiss your requests with extreme prejudice.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it crashes when it does not see the hostname entered in the line gethostbyname function. The reason that it crashes on other systems because I was not able to declare the server name in the host file located in C://Windows/System32/drivers/etc/host. If you have your own server and you wish to use the function gethostbyname, this is a crucial step in running the program.

THank you to Roger Rowland that made me realize this problem.